# PostgreSQL Referencing Outer Query in Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two Postgres tables (really, more than that, but simplified for the purpose of the question) - one a record of products that have been ordered by customers, and another a historical record of prices per customer and a date they went into effect. Something like this:

### 'orders' table

```
customer_id | timestamp           | quantity
------------+---------------------+---------
1           | 2015-09-29 16:01:01 | 5
1           | 2015-10-23 14:33:36 | 3
2           | 2015-10-19 09:43:02 | 7
1           | 2015-11-16 15:08:32 | 2
```

### 'prices' table

```
customer_id | effective_time      | price
------------+---------------------+-------
1           | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 15.00
1           | 2015-10-01 00:00:00 | 12.00
2           | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 14.00
```

I'm trying to create a query that will return every order and its unit price for that customer at the time of the order, like this:

### desired result

```
customer_id | quantity | price
------------+----------+------
1           | 5        | 15.00
1           | 3        | 12.00
2           | 7        | 14.00
1           | 2        | 12.00
```

This is essentially what I want, but I know that you can't reference an outer query inside an inner query, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to re-factor:

```
SELECT
    o.customer_id,
    o.quantity,
    p.price
FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT price
        FROM prices x
        WHERE x.customer_id = o.customer_id
            AND x.effective_time <= o.timestamp
        ORDER BY x.effective_time DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) p
;
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to make this work?

Comment: You can reference the `orders` table in the join query if you use `join lateral`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of joining an inline view based on the `prices` table, you can perform a subquery in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT customer_id, quantity, (
    SELECT price
    FROM prices p
    WHERE
      p.customer_id = o.customer_id
        AND p.effective_time <= o.timestamp
    ORDER BY p.effective_time DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS price
FROM orders o
```

That does rely on a correlated subquery, which could be bad for performance, but with the way your data are structured I doubt there's a substantially better alternative.

Comment: Okay, yeah, this makes sense. I'll give this a shot and hopefully performance won't be an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the subquery, just a plain inner join will do (this assumes there are no duplicate effective_times per customer):

```
SELECT o.customer_id, o.quantity
    ,p.price
FROM orders o
JOIN prices p ON p.customer_id = o.customer_id
              AND p.effective_time <= o.timestamp
              AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM prices nx
                  WHERE nx.customer_id = o.customer_id
                  AND nx.effective_time <= o.timestamp
                  AND nx.effective_time > p.effective_time
              )
    ;
```

Comment: Okay... interesting. That could work. It still has a subquery though -- do you have any idea what the performance would be like related to @JohnBollinger 's answer above?

Comment: Performance is probably the same. Only a subquery using rownumber() over (partition by customer_id ORDER BY effective_time DESC) could possibly perform better.